# Call Javascript Function in PHP Echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

With reference to [This link](http://www.91weblessons.com/animated-ajax-record-deletion-using-jquery-php/)
, I am trying to delete rows dynamically from a table. Here's my Javascript function:

```
function deleteBox(id){

alert ("Inside Method");
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?"))
{
  var dataString = 'id='+ id;
  $("#flash_"+id).show();
  $("#flash_"+id).fadeIn(400).html('<img src="img/loading.gif" /> ');
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "delete.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
           if(result){
                $("#flash_"+id).hide();
                // if data delete successfully
                if(result=='success'){
                     //Check random no, for animated type of effect
                     var randNum=Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
                     if(randNum % 2==0){
                        // Delete with slide up effect
                        $("#list_"+id).slideUp(1000);
                     }else{
                        // Just hide data
                        $("#list_"+id).hide(500);
                     }

                }else{
                     var errorMessage=result.substring(position+2);
                     alert(errorMessage);
                }
          }
  }
  });
}
}
```

However, calling it from **Echo** in Php, doesn't seem to invoke it. Here's my PHP code:

```
echo "<td align=\"center\">" . $id."</td>";
echo "<td><a href = 'javascript:deleteBox($id)'>Delete</a></td>";
```

Please correct me wherever I'm goin wrong. An early help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please make a fiddle.

Comment: it wont be invoked till you click the anchor tag, and if `$id` is text containing quotes it is going to mess up with the html markup

Comment: www.jsfiddle.net doesn't allow to make PHP fiddles.. I'm very new to this stuff so appologize for being stupid :(

Comment: @PatrickEvans so how do I call it then? `$id` is just a simple integer e.g 202, 183 etc.

Comment: When do you wish to have it being called, not in click event?

Comment: Well i assume you only want it to delete when it is clicked, which is what it should be doing as is, was just meaning that your language suggested that you expect the javascript function to execute as soon as it is echoed.

Comment: It's not deleting any record afterbeing clicked. Not even showing the alert message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td><a href = 'javascript:deleteBox($id)'>Delete</a></td>
```

to

```
echo "<td><a onClick='deleteBox(" . $id . ");'>Delete</a></td>";
```

In my opinion, thats how I would do it..

Edited and shortened the jscript;

```
function deleteBox(idDelete){

alert ("Inside Method");
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?"))
{
  $("#flash_" + idDelete).show();
  $("#flash_" + idDelete).fadeIn(400).html('<img src="img/loading.gif" /> ');

  $.post('delete.php', {'id': idDelete}, function(result) {
            if(result){
                $("#flash_" + idDelete).hide();
                // if data delete successfully
                if(result=='success'){
                     //Check random no, for animated type of effect
                     var randNum=Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
                     if(randNum % 2==0){
                        // Delete with slide up effect
                        $("#list_" + idDelete).slideUp(1000);
                     }else{
                        // Just hide data
                        $("#list_" + idDelete).hide(500);
                     }

                }else{
                     var errorMessage=result.substring(position+2);
                     alert(errorMessage);
                }
          }
  });  
}
```

in your delete.php:

```
$_POST['id']
```

to retrieve the ID.

Comment: can you please show me the same code inside PHP Echo? I guess the quotesare being messed up inside Echo, outside it works fine..

Comment: here you go:

echo "<td><a onClick='deleteBox(" . $id . ");'>Delete</a></td>";

That should work fine.

Comment: are you getting the ID variable properly?

Comment: Check the response with FireBug, and see the console retrieving, its probably that you're not setting $id, check whats set inside the deleteBox(id) in the HTML.

Comment: BelthazorNv thanks for your edit. But as per my understanding, even if there was something wrong with the delete.php page, it would still give alert ("Inside Method") atleaset.. But it isn't giving it.. means itsn't being called in the first place..

Comment: I cannot help you unless you show me your files, I have no idea how you're retrieving inside your delete.php nor how you're responding.

Comment: either host the files somewhere maybe dropbox or something :s

Answer (score 1):

Check this, Hope this helps.  Instead of id, static values are given

```
<td align="center">1</td>
<td><a href='#' onclick='deleteBox(1)'>Delete</a></td>

echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='deleteBox(1)'>Delete</a></td>";
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s98NC/1/)

I am updating the answer, check whether alert is working.

```
<script>
function deleteBox(a){
    alert(a);
}   
</script>

<?php
  echo "<a href='#' onclick='deleteBox(1)'>Delete</a>";
?>
```

Comment: please show it how to use it within Echo in PHP.. I have to useit inside Echo and I think I'm messing up with the quotes somewhere..

Comment: echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='deleteBox(1)'>Delete</a></td>";

Comment: I'm cpoy-pasting the exact code but still it's not invoking the Javascript function :( Please help :(

Comment: Not working means?  Are you getting the alert message?

Comment: Try the updated answer. Check whether you are getting value of a in the alert

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, I wouldn't do the call to the function in the href. Try something like this:

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
$('.delete').click(function() {

var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

alert ("Inside Method");
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?"))
{
  var dataString = 'id='+ id;
  $("#flash_"+id).show();
  $("#flash_"+id).fadeIn(400).html('<img src="img/loading.gif" /> ');
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "delete.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
           if(result){
                $("#flash_"+id).hide();
                // if data delete successfully
                if(result=='success'){
                     //Check random no, for animated type of effect
                     var randNum=Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
                     if(randNum % 2==0){
                        // Delete with slide up effect
                        $("#list_"+id).slideUp(1000);
                     }else{
                        // Just hide data
                        $("#list_"+id).hide(500);
                     }

                }else{
                     var errorMessage=result.substring(position+2);
                     alert(errorMessage);
                }
          }
  }
  });
});
});
```

PHP/HTML:

```
echo "<td align=\"center\">" . $id."</td>";
echo "<td><a class='delete' data-id='" . $id . "'>Delete</a></td>";
```

Comment: I did that but it's not a clickable link

Comment: What do you mean? If it's an a tag, it can be clicked?

Comment: I did what you said but now Delete option is not coming clickable :(

Comment: You mean that the mouse doesn't indicate that you can click it? Try `echo "<td><a class='delete' style='cursor: pointer;' data-id='" . $id . "'>Delete</a></td>";`.

Comment: that's execatly what I meant. But now it is clickable but doesn't do anything after I click it :(

Comment: Check my updated answer. Added `$(function() { })` around the click listener, so it waits for the document to load properly before trying to add the event listener to the link.

Comment: Oh you edited it.. I thought I didn't see it initially. Did the same thing, still useless :(

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors in the browser console?