# Supplying an onclick method with argument on echo in php

Tags: javascript, php

Is there a better way to supply an `onclick` function assignment to something `echo`ed in php? I'm trying to open a modal `div` once an `<a>` link or `<button>` is clicked.

```
<div id="modalBox" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
        <div class="w3-container">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('modalBox').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
            <p>Some text. Some text. Some text.</p>
            <p>Some text. Some text. Some text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="record-container">
    <table class="table-record">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Control</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        $announcementDaoImpl = new AnnouncementDaoImpl($pdo);
        $announcementList = $announcementDaoImpl->getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent();
        foreach ($announcementList as $key => $value) {
            $announcementTitle = $value->getTitle();
            $dateCreated = $value->getDateAdded();
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $announcementTitle . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $dateCreated . "</td>";
            echo "<td><button onclick='showEditModal()'>" . "Edit" . "</button></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
         }
         ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

This line,

```
echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='showEditModal()'>" . "Edit" . "</a></td>";
```

I assigned `showEditModal()` as method so that once the **Edit** button is clicked, it will call on this method to display the modal box. However, I'm having problems with *double quotes* and *single quotes* because the `showEditModal()` method expects an argument.

```
function showEditModal(modalDivId){
    var modalBox = document.getElementById(modalDivId);
    modalBox.style.display = "block";
}
```

I even tried this.

```
echo "<td><button onclick=\"showEditModal('modalBox')\">" . "Edit" . "</button></td>";
```

No luck. The modal box won't show. Even an `alert()` won't show.

How can I supply the argument on `echo`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With proper handling of quotes characters in string, escaped `"` because string delimiter is the same.

**Try:**

```
echo "<td><a href='#' onclick=\"showEditModal('modal1')\">" . "Edit" . "</a></td>";
```

Just change the value of 'modal1' to the right element id.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to handle such problems, one option is [PHPs alternative syntax](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php);

```
<div class="record-container">
    <table class="table-record">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Control</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        $announcementDaoImpl = new AnnouncementDaoImpl($pdo);
        $announcementList = $announcementDaoImpl->getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent();
        foreach($announcementList as $key => $value): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $key->getTitle(); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->getDateAdded(); ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" onclick="showEditModal('modalBox')">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know about that alternative syntax but it looks neat. I'll surely use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link [How to call a JavaScript function from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php)

Or [Call Javascript Function in PHP Echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968775/call-javascript-function-in-php-echo)

Answer (score 0):

> **Separate the html from the server language and it will be more readable**

```
<div class="record-container">
    <table class="table-record">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Control</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
         $announcementDaoImpl = new AnnouncementDaoImpl($pdo);
         $announcementList = $announcementDaoImpl->getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent();
         foreach ($announcementList as $key => $value):
            $announcementTitle = $value->getTitle();
            $dateCreated = $value->getDateAdded();
            /* comment: "<?=$var?>" this is equal to "echo $var;" endcomment */ 
        ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?= $announcementTitle ?></td>
              <td><?= $dateCreated ?></td>";
              <td>
               <button onclick="showEditModal('<?=$your_variable?>')">
                Edit
               </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
         <?php 
          endforeach; 
         ?>

    </table>
</div>
```